# OpenERP model tracking external resource, hooking into parent's copy() or copy_data()

Tags: model, copy, odoo

I have added a new model (call it crm_lead_external) that is linked via a new one2many on crm_lead.

Thus, my module has two models defined: an updated crm_lead (with _name=crm_lead) and a new crm_lead_external.

This external model tracks a file and as such has a 'filename' field.

I also created a unique SQL index on this filename field.

This is part of my module:

```
def copy(self, cr, uid, id, default=None, context=None):
    if not default:
        default = {}
    default.update({
        'state': 'new',
        'filename': '',
    })
    ret = super(crm_lead_external, self).copy(cr, uid, id, default, context=context)
    #do file copy
    return ret
```

The intent here is to allow an external entity to be duplicated, but to retarget the file path.

Now, if I click duplicate on the Lead, I get an IntegrityError on my unique constraint. Is there a particular reason why copy() isn't being called?

Should I add this logic to copy_data()? Myst I really override copy() for the lead?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two [`osv` class methods](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/03_modules_2.html#orm-methods): `copy` and `copy_data`, which are accessible to all `osv` subclasses, such as your `crm_lead_external` class.

When you click Duplicate it calls `osv.copy()`. If your model contains any relational fields and those fields have any records linked then `osv` will call `copy_data()` on the linked records. In your case, when you call `copy` on model `crm.lead`, it calls `copy_data()` on `crm_lead_external`. You have a UNIQUE constraint on `crm_lead_external`, and that causes your error message.

There can be two fixes to this problem.

1. If you don't want to copy `crm_lead_external` records, then override the `copy` method of the `crm.lead` model and disable copying of the `crm_lead_external` oem field values.

   ```
   def copy(self, cr, uid, id, default=None, context=None):
       if default is None:
           default = {}
       default['o2m_field'] = []
       return super(<calss_name>, self).copy(cr, uid, id, default, context)
   ```

   This will stop copying the o2m field record.
2. We will override the `copy` method of your model `crm_lead_extenal` so every time `copy_data` is called, we will resolve the UNIQUE constraint stuff and and pass new values so you will not encounter any issues.

   ```
   def copy_data(self, cr, uid, id, default=None, context=None):
       if default is None:
           default = {}
       default['name'] = self.browse(cr, uid, id, context=context).name or ''
       if not context.get('copy',False):
           new_name = _("%s (copy)")%default.get('name','')
           default.update({'name':new_name})
       return super(<calss_bame>, self).copy_data(cr, uid, id, default, context)
   ```

   In this example, I have appended copy text at the end of the name so I will always get a new name, likewise you can avoid UNIQUE constraints like this, and you will have all the data copied perfectly.

Comment: So yeah, my options are either overriding the parent (crm.lead) copy() or overriding the child (crm.lead.external) copy_data(). Drat.

Okay, thanks for the information. I won't override copy_data(), since I don't know where to copy the external resource yet, so I'll probably do method 1 (clearing the default) and then doing a manual custom copy of the object.

Answer (score 0):

just change the value of the unique fields in copy method. like adding " COPY" after the original value.

you can have en example in addons/product/product.py line no 660

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
def copy(self,cr,uid,id,default = None,context = None):
        print"---------Calling copy function----"
        print default

                return super(demo_courses, self).copy(cr, uid, id, default, context)
```

Comment: Please add a few lines to explain why you think your solution is a good answer to the original question, thanks.